# Using pandas or dictionary for apis?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My api recieves a dataset in json format. At the moment it turns it into a panda dataframe and then does a number of functions on it. Is this an acceptable way to do things or should i turn the json in to a dictionary and use map()?

I was told pandas should only be used for data analysis and I should not use it for api's can some one confirm this?

thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you cannot use pandas for what you do.

Comment: If it's simply you might want to avoid pandas. But if you as you say "does a number of functions on it" .. I'd say why not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "does a number of functions on it". That would give a clear idea on your goal. If your intention is to perform a groupby or aggregation or something of that sort, pandas is a good choice. If your intention is to just loop through the json and validate the values against condition(s), pandas wouldn't be required to do so as there are pythonic ways to do it.